# How to Fix Frame Size Error When Making Animation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, video

I have this code to create an animation:

```
obj = VideoWriter(pvideo);
open(obj);
pic=dir(strcat(outputs,'/','*.tif'));
num=length(pic); 
for i=1:num 
    im = imread(strcat(outputs,'/',pic(i).name)); 
    writeVideo(obj,im);
end 
close(obj)
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 368)
Frame must be 1768 by 1326
```

I understand that my video dimensions are off, but I'm not sure what part of my code needs to be changed to fix this.

Comment: Do all `.tiff` images/files being used have the same dimensions? Might be having an issue appending images that do not have the same resolution sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Size Mismatch

I believe a possible issue is that the images being combined into the video file may not match in resolution/dimensional size. Here is a sample script that creates a video file from built-in MATLAB images. Here all the images are written as size 500 by 500. If one of the images are not matching the error is thrown. They're are two ways to handle the issue resize the image using the `imresize()` function or crop the image using the `imcrop()` function or indexing **(this can be done in the for-loop)**. Can one of the `500` dimensions in the script below throws the same error which might be an indicator of this problem.

[image]

```
%Creating test images to combine into video file%
Folder_Path = "";
Image = imresize(imread('moon.tif'),[500 500]);
imwrite(Image,fullfile(Folder_Path,"Image_1.tif"));
Image = imresize(imread('circuit.tif'),[500 500]);
imwrite(Image,fullfile(Folder_Path,"Image_2.tif"));
Image = imresize(imread('autumn.tif'),[500 500]);
imwrite(Image,fullfile(Folder_Path,"Image_3.tif"));

%Starting to create video%
Pictures = dir(fullfile(Folder_Path,'*.tif'));
    
%Creating a video object to save the video structure to%
Video_Object = VideoWriter('Saved_Video.mp4','MPEG-4'); 
Video_Object.FrameRate = 1; 
Video_Object.Quality = 100;
Number_Of_Frames = length(Pictures);
open(Video_Object);


%Scanning the frames into the video structure%
for Frame_Index = 1: Number_Of_Frames
    writeVideo(Video_Object,imread(fullfile(Folder_Path,Pictures(Frame_Index).name)));
end

close(Video_Object);
implay('Saved_Video.mp4');
```